# MySql not working on Amazon EC2

Tags: java, mysql, spring, amazon-ec2

I have a java spring application deployed on tomcat7 on Amazon EC2 Linux AMI. Mysql is running on the same instance. I can connect to the mysql server remotely using SSH connection. But not able to access mysql server from spring application.
Tomcat's  context.xml looks like :

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/db"   
       auth="Container"   
       type="javax.sql.DataSource"   
       uniqueResourceName="jdbc/db"   
       username="root"   
       password="pass"   
       driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"  
       maxActive="15"  
       maxIdle="7"  
       validationQuery="Select 1" />
```

This doesn't work, actually I'm not able to figure out whether db is connected or no as it throws no error. 
But when I replace localhost with server running on some other instance it works as expected. 
Would be helpful if someone point out where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is port 3306 open? The EC2 default security group controls which ports can be accessed by new instances, and is pretty restrictive by default. Log in to the [AWS Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) and check that you don't have restrictive rules under EC2 > Network & Security > Security Groups.

Comment: That I have already done. I'm able to connect to mysql remotely but cannot connect to it from the application hosted on same instance. I have similar windows instance where application and db reside on same instance there it works fine. But the same configuration isn't working on linux. Everything else is working except db connection.

Comment: Are your MySQL roles defined with wildcards? A rule like

    `GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'root'@'some.domain.name'`

won't work if you're connecting from `localhost`. Instead, you'll want to

    `GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'root'@'%'`

Answer (score 0):

try read tomcat error - nano usr/share/tomcat8/logs/catalina.out

in my connection.property file i have writed code like this

```
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root&password=pass
```

the app which runs under tomcat8 connects to local mysql and everything ok. Simple read error context may be some thing does not exist or becaouse of case sensitivenes mysql throws error.